# What's wrong with the argument $\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I will just quote an argument given in the book Analysis 1 by Terence Tao.

> Start with the expression $\lim_{x→\infty}\sin(x)$ , make the change of variable $x=y+\pi$ and recall that $\sin(y+\pi)=-\sin(y)$ to obtain
>   $$\lim_{x→\infty}\sin(x)=\lim_{y+\pi→\infty}\sin(y+\pi)=\lim_{y→\infty}-\sin(y)=-\lim_{y→\infty}\sin(y)$$
>   Since $\lim_{x→\infty}\sin(x)=\lim_{y→\infty}\sin(y)$ we thus have$$\lim_{x→\infty}\sin(x)=-\lim_{x→\infty}\sin(x)$$
>   and hence$$\lim_{x→\infty}\sin(x)=0$$
>   If we then make the change of variable $x=\pi/2+z$ and recall that $\sin(\pi/2+z)=\cos(z)$ we conclude that $$\lim_{x→\infty}\cos(x)=0$$
>   Squaring both of these limits and adding we see that$$\lim_{x→\infty}(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))=0^2+0^2=0$$
>   On the other hand we have $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$

Although I have read the relevant portion from the book, I am still not able to understand the fault in the above argument.

Comment: Limit does not exist

Comment: You can use `\to` to get an arrow for limits: `\lim_{x\to\infty}` is $$\lim_{x\to\infty}.$$

Comment: @MJD ok thanks. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$ does not exist.

Comment: Ok. So we can manipulate limits and do limit operations only if they exist right?

Comment: Yes. $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x=-\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$ doesn't make sense, since none of the sides of the identity is defined.

Comment: It is a proof by contradiction.  We make some assumption at the start, then deduce a contradiction.  So we conclude the assumption was false.